# html form submiting more fields than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I'm dealing with a awful issue, I developed a form with multi fields set (using normal div)
and when I test the submit action I got in the URL the one input not filled, also hidden in
the markup as showed bellow.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/exform.html?user=test&pwd=QWERT1234&user_reg=
```

And here is the code for the form:

```
<form id="exform">
            <div class="fields" id="login">
                <div class="txt">
                  <label for="user"></label>
                  <input id="user" type="text" name="user"/>
                </div>

                <div class="txt">
                  <label for="pwd"</label>
                  <input id="pwd" type="password" name="pwd"  />
                </div>
                  <input type="submit" value="test" id="test"/>
            </div>

            <div class="fields" id="register">

                <div class="txt">
                  <label for="user_reg"></label>
                  <input id="user_reg" name="user_reg" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <div class="txt">
                  <label for="pwd2"></label>
                  <input id="pwd2" type="password" />
                </div>

                <div class="txt">
                  <label for="pwdc"></label>
                  <input id="pwdc" type="password"/>

                </div>

                <div class="buttons">
                  <input type="submit" value="OK" id="ok"/>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

The strange is that the second field set isn't available in the screen, because in the css 
there is a rule to only show the first group with the class "fields"

```
/*Hide all except first div with class div*/
#exform .fields:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

So I really want to know why the form is submitting fields out of the scope.

For example,  if the second group fieldset is used, when the button submit with value OK is clicked the result produced is similar. In the URL,  only the user_reg field parameter is showed filled with the two another fields for the first group without values:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/exform.html?user=&pwd=&user_reg=test
```

The following code is for submit test:

```
$(function() {

    $('#test').click(function() {
         $('#exform').submit(function(event) {
           console.log("form Submited:" + document.forms['exform'] + "test");
         });
    });
    $('#ok').click(function() {

         $('#exform').submit(function(event) {
           console.log("form Submited:" + document.forms['exform'] + "ok");
         });
    });
});
```

Doesn't matter I'm got the same URL results

This

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/exform.html?user=test&pwd=QWERT1234&user_reg=
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/exform.html?user=&pwd=&user_reg=test
```

Instead I'm receiving:

```
// on #test click
http://127.0.0.1:8000/exform.html?user=test&pwd=QWERT1234     

// on #ok click
http://127.0.0.1:8000/exform.html?user_reg=test&pwd2=QWERT1234&pwdc=QWERT123
```

I can't retrieve the values for pwd2 and pwdc fields in the URL as parameters obtained after submitting.

This got me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify the `method` method of the form, the default is `GET` while submitting it. This is the reason to see all form elements in your URL.
Try this:

```
<form id="exform" method="post">
<!-- form contents -->
```

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1) for details.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit form you submit all it's input fields at ones.

Even if you hide something with css it still exists in html.

When you processed the form you can add a hidden field "input type="hidden"" and give that field a value that tells your script witch fields you want processed in witch case.

And i also fink that post method is better (more secure) especially if you send password.